# How to connect php file with android and get back response

Tags: php, android, post, location

**I want only connect php file with android**
here i send current latitude and longitude to php and get back response. but
not succeed.

I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost or 10.0.2.1 or 10.0.2.2 it is the same

**I'm new in android.**

**this is errors**

```
1. Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused Error converting 
2. java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
```

**here is my method**

```
private void Send_Location(final double longitudeNetwork, double latitudeNetwork) {
    final String urlSuffix = "?longitude="+longitudeNetwork+"&latitude="+latitudeNetwork;

    class Get_Location extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        InputStream is = null;
        String line = null;
        String result=null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String s = strings[0];
            try{
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/new/demo.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("log_tag", "connect==");
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection =="+e.toString());
            }
            try{

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while (response != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();

                Log.e("log_tag", "success==== "+result);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result=="+e.toString());
            }
            return result;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
    Get_Location gl = new Get_Location();
    gl.execute(urlSuffix);
}
```

Comment: use your `IP` address its working for me

Comment: Find the IP of your computer and use that instead 127.0.0.1. .. `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are the addresses of the current machine e.g. emulator/phone not on the computer/server

Comment: are you using genymotion?

Comment: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.1.15:80 timed out-------------error

Comment: You did not tell where the php is runing. You also still did not tell where your app is running. Emulator or Android device? You should have started your post with it.

Comment: I have run this app in my mobile.and php file is in localhost lampp server.

Comment: From the emulator point of view `localhost`,  `10.0.2.1` or `10.0.2.2` are not the same. `localhost` refers to the emulator itself. `10.0.2.1` refers to the virtual router (which is not accessible from the emulator AFAIK). And `10.0.2.2` refers to the host machine's loopback/localhost.